# Can value return from method are assignable for constant?

Tags: java, performance

I want to format some files in SpringBoot with one request for each file. With each request, I have to call the getOutputFolder(dirName) method to get an output path in order to save the file in the expected path but my solution comes with high at overhead cost. I want to define one constant and then when I have to call the function I instead call this. But I feel it seems to be wrong or at least like a sneaky way to do. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

```
private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH = getOutputFolderPath();

private String getOutputFolder(String dirName) {
    String pathStr = getOutputFolderPath() + dirName + File.separator + "submit" + File.separator;
    Path outputDirPath = Paths.get(pathStr);

    Path path = null;
    boolean dirExists = Files.exists(outputDirPath);
    if (!dirExists) {
        try {
            path = Files.createDirectories(outputDirPath);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            logger.error("Error occur when create the folder at: {}", pathStr);
        }
    }
    return dirExists ? pathStr : Objects.requireNonNull(path).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [jcache](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/javax.cache/cache-api/1.0.0/index.html).

To do this, you need to install it to your Spring Boot project

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation 'javax.cache:cache-api:1.1.0'

// or the maven equivalent if you are using maven
```

Then create a `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager` bean to configure the cache.

```java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
  CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
  CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();

  // The class arguments is <String, String> because the method to cache accepts a String and returns a String
  // just explore this object for the config you need.
  MutableConfiguration<String, String> configuration = new MutableConfiguration<>();

  String cacheName = "OUTPUT_FOLDER_CACHE";
  cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, configuration);
  return cacheManager;
}
```

When this is setup, you can now annotated the method to be cached.

```java
@Cacheable(
  cacheNames = { "OUTPUT_FOLDER_CACHE" }, // The same string in config
  unless = "#result == null" // Dont' cache null result; or do, if you need it.
)
String getOutputFolder(String dirName) {
  // method contents...
}
```

When properly configured: the method will return the cache value if it exists, or run the actual method, cache the result and return the result if the cached value does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the getOuputFolder(dirName) method takes an argument from the request param of an API. Can you customize your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that issue by using ThreadLocal. 
A threadlocal can store value and you can make useful for yourself. Suppose if your getOutputFolderPath() is different for different request then you can 
store the getOutputFolderPath() value while a new request dispatched on server and you can do your all operation upto your request live.

[See Threadlocal Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

```
@Service
public class FileSaveService {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> path=new ThreadLocal<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setPath(getOutputFolderPath());
    }

    public void setPath(String pathString) {
        path.set(pathString);
    }

    public String getPath() {
        if(path.get() == null) return getOutputFolderPath();
        return path.get();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        path.remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that the question requires `ThreadLocal`, but using `@PostConstruct` seems to be a good alternative to the static wannabe constant.